# socket.io http listen on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to connect an wamp server on localhost which is a html page.

So far, I have this:

```
//SOCKET.IO Setup
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http); //initialise after http server

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
http.listen('/wheel', function(){
  console.log('listening on */wheel');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('wheel.html');
});
```

I have the HTML Page inside www/wheel and the html page is called wheel.html

This is the error I get:

```
[17:08:51] error  - Error: listen EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1139:19)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1261:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Family\wheel.js:14:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

How do I correctly connect to a web directory in my localhost using socket.io? It works when I use a socket and port:

```
http.listen(1000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:1000');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('wheel.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to make the HTTP server listen on a [UNIX socket](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback) called `/wheel`, and you don't have the correct privileges to create that file.

If you want to be able to serve the HTML file when a client calls `/` on your server (which, for instance, is listening on port 3000):

```
http.listen(3000);
...
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./www/wheel/wheel.html');
});
```

Comment: Hey! That makes more sense thanks. My main concern now is that I've moved nodule_modules to the /www/ directory because the html file needs 'socket.io/socket.io.js'. But when I look inside /node_modules/socket.io there isn't the socket.io.js file. However it is inside C:\wamp\www\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io.js

Comment: Basically, I can't point the paths to the wamp directory www?

Comment: @BradlySpicer socket.io will automatically "catch" requests to the client-side .js file and handle it for you, you don't have to do anything for that. For generic static file handling, you may want to look at Express' [`static`](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) middleware.